# Python- using a string as a lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda

Say I have the following string

```
a = "x**2+5"
```

and I want to use it to create the following lambda function:

```
b= lambda x: x**2+5
```

How do I do so?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `eval()`: `b = lambda x: eval(a)`. Just remember that using `eval()` in a real program, where you do not have control over `a` and `x`, may cause tons of problems.

Comment: I warned you :) https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html